# Does the Amazon Kindle app run on Android 7.1.1?

Tags: nexus, kindle-for-android

I'm setting up a Nexus 9 tablet for a friend. I flashed the Android v7.1.1 March update image then installed [the Amazon Kindle app from the App Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle&hl=en_GB). The problem is that when I open the app and tap the *Start Reading* button the app hangs with a blank white screen.

The Android app runs find on my OnePlus 3 with Android 7.0, so I'm wondering if something in the latest Android version has broken it.

I guess I could flash a v7.0 image onto the Nexus 9, and I will do that if no-one here can confirm the problem with v7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I have pinpointed the problem by flashing an older version of Android. These tests were done on my 16GB Nexus 9.

- With a freshly flashed version of Android v7.1.1, with all user data wiped, the Kindle app hangs when you click the *Start Reading* button.
- With a freshly flashed version of Android v7.0, with all user data wiped, the Kindle app runs normally. Clicking the *Start Reading* button allows me to enter my Amazon account details and start reading.
- If I let my tablet download the updates to v7.1.1 and install them, without wiping the user data, then the Kindle app still runs normally. So the app does run on v7.1.1.
- But ... if I now delete the Kindle cache and data from Settings/Apps then the Kindle app once again hangs when you click the *Start Reading* button.

So the problem is specific to the v7.1.1 version of Android, but the problem is limited to whatever bit of the Kindle app configures your Amazon account.

In theory there is an update to v7.1.1 on its way to my OnePlus 3 phone, and when that arrives I will try the same experiment to see whether it is a device specific problem.